# Finding files with one occurrence of regex pattern or less. Grep?

Tags: regex, grep

I was looking for a tool to recursively find files that have one or 0 occurence of a regex pattern.

I first thought of grep but I could reach watch I was looking for.

Do you have any clue ?

Comment: "but I could reach watch I was looking for" ? I guess you're looking for either `egrep` or `grep -e`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `egrep` to recursively search files for regex matches:

```
egrep -l -R -e "[0-9]+" ~/tmp
```

The -l option tells `egrep` to list only the files that match the regex. Remove it if you also want to see the lines that match the regex.